# illustrator shortcut - reset zoom to fit artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts, zoom

I Sometimes over zoom.

When using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> + mouse-drag it gives me a zoom box but sometimes i pick a small box and zooms in too much.

Is there any shortcut to **reset current artboard to fit my screen**?

My workaround to zoom out is to do (multiple times) - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> + click

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fit in Window: <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> (that's a zero).

Answer (score 2):

You can also fit at 100% of your artwork (not screen): <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.